# Maven codecoverage for java and scala

Tags: java, scala, maven, code-coverage

There are some module in **java** and others in **Scala** in my **maven project** .

I have written unit test case for java and Scala Module .

Now I want to check **codecoverage** for my project .

What **plugins** should i use and what will be the **command** to execute them .

Please help me . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try JaCoCo EclEmma Maven plugin:

http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

Comment: You can use scoverage for Scala. https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin

Comment: I am afraid there is no common plugin for this purpose.